# what are the cases i need to take for using maclaurin expansion for log(1+x)?

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

While expanding log (1+x) as a infinite sum using maclaurin series, i understand that i need to satisfy the condition that lagrange's form of remainder Rn limits to zero as n limits to infinity.

[image]

but how to take up the cases for x such that above condition is satisfied?
i tried considering positive and negative cases but not getting anything,
any hint would be highly appreciated.

PS: please guide me how to put my doubts clearly as I'm unable to post any new questions because as per stack exchange i need to improve the questions asked so far and I don't want to open a new account to ask new questions.

Comment: Are you talking about the interval of convergence for the Maclaurin series, or what?

Comment: $\log(x)$ is defined for $x>0$ so $\log(1+x)$ is defined for $x > -1$.  But the Taylor series $\log(1+x)=x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13x^3-\frac14x^4+\cdots$ has a radius of convergence of $1$ in that it does not converge if $x>1$ or $x\le -1$ and only converges conditionally if $x=1$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the [Mercator Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) and its convergence radius.

Comment: So the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ has this special name... Next time I would use this term when I am doing a proof by intimidation... :|